# How to compress all responses with Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1

1. Why Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression don't compress all responses?
2. Will be any problems if add lot of mime-types?
3. Is there any libs with mime-types constant lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like there is no option to compress all responses, so I create collection with common mime types

```
services.AddResponseCompression(options => { options.MimeTypes = MimeTypes.CommonMimeTypes; });
```

```
internal static class MimeTypes
{
    public static readonly IEnumerable<string> CommonMimeTypes = new[]
    {
        "application/javascript",
        "application/json",
        "application/ld+json",
        "application/msword",
        "application/octet-stream",
        "application/ogg",
        "application/pdf",
        "application/rtf",
        "application/vnd.apple.installer+xml",
        "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "application/vnd.visio",
        "application/x-csh",
        "application/x-sh",
        "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "application/xhtml+xml",
        "application/xml",
        "audio/3gpp",
        "audio/3gpp2",
        "audio/aac",
        "audio/midi",
        "audio/x-midi",
        "audio/mpeg",
        "audio/ogg",
        "audio/opus",
        "audio/wav",
        "audio/webm",
        "font/otf",
        "font/ttf",
        "font/woff",
        "font/woff2",
        "image/bmp",
        "image/gif",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/png",
        "image/svg+xml",
        "image/tiff",
        "image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
        "image/webp",
        "text/calendar",
        "text/css",
        "text/csv",
        "text/html",
        "text/javascript",
        "text/json",
        "text/plain",
        "text/xml",
        "video/3gpp",
        "video/3gpp2",
        "video/mp2t",
        "video/mpeg",
        "video/ogg",
        "video/webm",
        "video/x-msvideo",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like there is an option to compress all responses. Add the mime type `*/*` to [ResponseCompressionOptions.MimeTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.responsecompression.responsecompressionoptions.mimetypes?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

```
services.AddResponseCompression((ResponseCompressionOptions options) =>
{
    // Support compression for any type of response.
    options.MimeTypes = new string[] { "*/*" };
});
```

---

This works because there is a check for the wildcard `*/*` in the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a379c1e614e0f7d8287da8237e04a328a6b9a89f/src/Middleware/ResponseCompression/src/ResponseCompressionProvider.cs#L204-L206) of the [ResponseCompressionProvider.ShouldCompressResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.responsecompression.responsecompressionprovider.shouldcompressresponse?view=aspnetcore-8.0) method:

```
        var shouldCompress = ShouldCompressExact(mimeType) //check exact match type/subtype
            ?? ShouldCompressPartial(mimeType) //check partial match type/*
            ?? _mimeTypes.Contains("*/*"); //check wildcard */*
```

---

Note from the [definition](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a379c1e614e0f7d8287da8237e04a328a6b9a89f/src/Middleware/ResponseCompression/src/ResponseCompressionProvider.cs#L233-L237) of `ShouldCompressExact` that this wildcard will not take precedence over any MIME type added to [ResponseCompressionOptions.ExcludedMimeTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.responsecompression.responsecompressionoptions.excludedmimetypes?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

```
    private bool? ShouldCompressExact(string mimeType)
    {
        //Check excluded MIME types first, then included
        if (_excludedMimeTypes.Contains(mimeType))
        {
            return false;
        }
```